Trying to Generate a PDF file from a newly created Google Doc file, non static
I am trying to generate a PDF file from a Google Doc file that was created from Google Forms. I would like it to work everytime someone submits data using the Google Form.
I don't know where to to put the code or how to. Below is my Script.
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
//e.values is an array of form values
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var firstName = e.values[1];
var lastName = e.values[2];
var mailingAddressLine1 = e.values[3];
var mailingAddressLine2 = e.values[4];
var mailingAddressLine3 = e.values[5];
var physicalAddressLine1 = e.values[6];
var physicalAddressLine2 = e.values[7];
var physicalAddressLine3 = e.values[8];
var date = e.values[9];
var description1 = e.values[10];
var description2 = e.values[11];
var description3 = e.values[12];
var description4 = e.values[13];
var description5 = e.values[14];
var description6 = e.values[15];
var description7 = e.values[16];
var description8 = e.values[17];
var description9 = e.values[18];
var description10 = e.values[19];
var description11 = e.values[20];
var description12 = e.values[21];
var total = e.values[22];



var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID'); 


var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID')
var copy = file.makeCopy(lastName + ',' + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + date, folder);

var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
var body = doc.getBody(); 


body.replaceText('{{FIRSTNAME}}', firstName); 
body.replaceText('{{LASTNAME}}', lastName);  
body.replaceText('{{MAILINGADDRESSLINE1}}', mailingAddressLine1);
body.replaceText('{{MAILINGADDRESSLINE2}}', mailingAddressLine2);
body.replaceText('{{MAILINGADDRESSLINE3}}', mailingAddressLine3);
body.replaceText('{{PHYSICALADDRESSLINE1}}', physicalAddressLine1);
body.replaceText('{{PHYSICALADDRESSLINE2}}', physicalAddressLine2);
body.replaceText('{{PHYSICALADDRESSLINE3}}', physicalAddressLine3);
body.replaceText('{{DATE}}', date);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION1}}', description1);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION2}}', description2);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION3}}', description3);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION4}}', description4);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION5}}', description5);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION6}}', description6);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION7}}', description7);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION8}}', description8);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION9}}', description9);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION10}}', description10);
body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION11}}', description11);
body.replace
doc.saveAndClose();

}

Please help me. Thank you.
Everything works, but I don't know where or how to write the script for PDF creation within my script.
